# iCloud: NSMetadataQuery return wrong results when I delete files in setting device

Tags: ios

- I download one song -> it is synced on `iCloud.
- I go to Setting -> iCloud -> Manage Storage -> my application to delete all files.
- I go to my application and check notification from (NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification and NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification) -> NSMetadataQuery.results return 1 item (old value)

Thank you very much in advance.

```
enter code here

    - (void)processiCloudFiles:(NSNotification *)notification {
         [_query disableUpdates];
         [_iCloudNames removeAllObjects];
         int totalItems = _query.resultCount; // it not update here
         //OR: _query.results
    }
    - (void)startQuerying {
         [self stopQuery];
         _query = [self documentQuery];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(processiCloudFiles:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                           object:nil];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(processiCloudFiles:)
                                             name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
                                           object:nil];
         [_query startQuery];
    }

    - (void)stopQuery {
       if (_query) {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:nil];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:nil];
         [_query stopQuery];
         _query = nil;
       }
    }

    - (NSMetadataQuery *)documentQuery {
       NSMetadataQuery * query = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
       if (query) {
          [query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];        
          NSString * filePattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*.%@", FILE_EXTENSION];
          [query setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@",
                         NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, filePattern]];
       }
       return query;
    }
```

Comment: Sometime NSMetadataQuery return wrong value. I fixed this issue by add tmp file when resume app and delete this file before this file uploading to iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user presses home button, you create temp file at Document folder. Do this because user maybe go to setting device and delete song.

When user goes to you application, you can delete this temp file so that iCloud can refresh list of data.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you please share any example code in detail how can we do this.